# Arch Linux - Acquire or Compile missing PHP extensions

Tags: arch-linux, compiling, php, yaourt, php7

I've installed my first Arch Linux setup, and loving it thus far, with the small exception of setting up my dev environment properly.

My previous OS was Ubuntu 16.04 on which I ran Nginx, PHP5.6-FPM and PHP7.0-FPM for my local Magento and Drupal development. Adding the `ppa:ondrej/php` repo, I was able to install all the additional PHP extensions I needed.

However now that I've migrated to Arch, things aren't that clear cut ... browsing the AUR, I don't see packages for things I would normally install, such as:

`php5.6-cli, php5.6-common, php5.6-json, php5.6-mysql, php5.6-mbstring, php5.6-curl, php5.6-sqlite3, php5.6-soap, php5.6-zip, php5.6-dev`, etc.

Similar thing goes for PHP7.0 extensions. So I proceeded with installing PHP5.6 and 7.0 by running:

`yaourt -S php56-fpm` & `yaourt -S php70-fpm`

Those package builds went along okay. I then opened the relevant php.ini files (`/etc/php56/php.ini` & `/etc/php70/php.ini`) to see that some of the extensions I required merely needed to be uncommented to be enabled.

However, for something like `php5.6-json`, `php5.6-common`, `php5.6-cli` or `php7.0-json` for instance, I can't find a package. I then thought that perhaps I need to compile them from source. I did try googling this only to get confused among the results that I received.

To start with I did download the `php-5.6.30` tarball from php.net and extracted it on my machine. In the `ext` folder I do see most of the additional extensions I need (except php5.6-cli and php5.6-common).

From this point I have no idea on how to proceed, but figure this is a great opportunity to learn more about my chosen OS for the future - no doubt I'll be needing it again!

So my long-winded explanation finally comes to an end here, but I'm reaching out to anyone out there who can help me solve this or help me understand it better.

Many many thanks!!

Comment: check the [unofficial repositories](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unofficial_user_repositories) -- these are Arch's PPAs.

Comment: The cli should be included in the "base" packages: `php56` and `php70`. I don't know what the "common" stuff is but it sounds like it's also in those "base" packages. The json stuff is built in php since 5.2.